# What do I do to prevent hernias?

Tags: bodybuilding, injury, injury-prevention, powerlifting, hernia

I am very interested in lifting weights but I have had an inguinal hernia about 8 month ago and even though I am back to lifting I really fear pushing myself to limits because I don't want a recursion.Any help or tips so that I can be more safe?

Comment: How was your hernia repaired? With a mesh implant, or sewed shut?

Comment: As far as I know it was a mesh through laparoscopic method.

Comment: I'll have to do some research but my initial thoughts would be to target/train the transverse abdominis.

Comment: @ChasingTimmy — tRA = dead on.  Inner core more specifically (that’s only one part)— I’ll elaborate when I get a min

Comment: Thanks for the information,I'd like to know how to train those, eagerly waiting for the details :)